# Error: `input` must not start with a slash when using `prefixUrl`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

As soon as I update gatsby packages to the latest version, now version 4.10.1, or any version after 4.6, it directly gives me this error without any change in the code:

```
 ERROR 

`input` must not start with a slash when using `prefixUrl`

  Error: `input` must not start with a slash when using `prefixUrl`
  
  - index.js:484 normalizeArguments
    [guidedby-react]/[got]/dist/source/core/index.js:484:23
  
  - create.js:112 got
    [guidedby-react]/[got]/dist/source/create.js:112:39
  
  - create.js:221 Function.got.stream
    [guidedby-react]/[got]/dist/source/create.js:221:37
  
  - fetch-file.js:80 
    [guidedby-react]/[gatsby-core-utils]/dist/remote-file-utils/fetch-file.js:80:32
  
  - new Promise
  
  - fetch-file.js:45 requestRemoteNode
    [guidedby-react]/[gatsby-core-utils]/dist/remote-file-utils/fetch-file.js:45:10
  
  - fetch-remote-file.js:204 fetchFile
    [guidedby-react]/[gatsby-core-utils]/dist/fetch-remote-file.js:204:61
  
  - fetch-remote-file.js:102 fetchWorker
    [guidedby-react]/[gatsby-core-utils]/dist/fetch-remote-file.js:102:26
  

not finished run static queries - 0.605s
```

This is not the case working with Gatsby version 4.6.0, but I need to use Image CDN so I use need to update the packages. I think there is a change in the trailing slash on a package of 4.7, but no matter how many searches and tweaks I do, the error remains.
What I've done so far:

- Remove all external **a href** links
- Put trailingSlash option in **gatsby-config**.js with different options (legacy, never, always).
  None of it works, and I have no problem working with the project on Gatsby 4.6, but I need to use Image CDN so I updated them. Any idea how to solve this problem. My repo is private, but as I said, the code develops and builds without any trouble working with 4.6, only update to higher versions create this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I get this when I change the wordpress URL from local to azure. I am currently trying to figure it out to:

Tried: updating to latest gatsby

when I use local - build works

when I use azure -
Error: `input` must not start with a slash when using `prefixUrl`

Will update when solved.

Comment: A comment would have suited better, this is not an answer .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31712813)